# Object state leaking between Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm new to Mocha and I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm curious how I can ensure that actions performed in one test do not effect another. For example, assume that I have a function `microbe` that returns an object that looks like:

```
{
  _state : {
    views : 'views'
  }

  set : function(key, val) { this._state[key] = val }
}
```

This is a majorly reduced version of what I'm working with, but it demonstrates what I'm testing, using a test suite such as:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('State', function() {

  var microbe = require('../microbe/index'), app;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    app = microbe();
  });

  it('should update the view location with app.set', function() {

    app.set('views', 'test');
    expect(app._state.views).to.equal('test');

  });

  it('should return "views" as the defualt view location', function() {
    expect(app._state.views).to.equal('views');
  });

});
```

The second test fails because the first test sets `app._state.views` to `'test'` so it overrides the default of `'views'`. I thought Mocha would isolate each test, but apparently not. I've tried to just re-instantiate the app for each test as shown using`beforeEach`, but it still seems to be leaky.

Whats the best way to do this? I know I could just reverse the order of the tests and it would technically pass, but I'd rather fix the issue itself than just avoid it

Answer (score -1):

It looks as if your function `microbe()` is behaving as a singleton.

The easiest way of having a fresh instance of your microbe is to use the `new` keyword within the `beforeEach()`:

`beforeEach(function(done) {
    app = new microbe();
  });`

Doing this, each execution of a test will start freshly with a 'default' instance of the object you are returning.

Comment: `microbe` is not a constructor so the `new` keyword would throw an error and it is not a singleton. It simply returns an object. Invoking the function just returns an object.

What you're recommending is essentially the same thing I'm already doing.

Comment: It's strange. I've reproduced your code and everything went like a charm. Tests passed with a copy paste of your code (I've implemented your microbe with a module exporting a single function that returns an object). Here is the gist for the code https://gist.github.com/javierfdezg/ee57103c9b461b18b9d8. Can you provide more info about the microbe/index.js implementation?

Comment: You can see the entire code base at https://github.com/Aweary/microbe.js. I'm thinking it's likely due to the `state` object being global within the application.

Comment: I'm looking for something like that. Mocha is doing it's job ok for what I can see

Comment: Just reviewed the code and it's likely to be the global state. Although your microbe function is not a constructor, try to put the new keyword as I suggested (it won't throw an error)

Answer (score -1):

I just tested the code you posted and the tests run correctly:

test.js:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('State', function() {

  var microbe = require('./microbe.js'), app;

  beforeEach(function() {
    app = microbe();
  });

  it('should update the view location with app.set', function() {

    app.set('views', 'test');
    expect(app._state.views).to.equal('test');

  });

  it('should return "views" as the defualt view location', function() {
    expect(app._state.views).to.equal('views');
  });

});
```

microbe.js:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {

    _state : {
      views : 'views'
    },
    set : function(key, val) { this._state[key] = val; }
  };
};
```

Executing mocha outputs:

```
/tmp  mocha -R spec test.js


  State
    ✓ should update the view location with app.set
    ✓ should return "views" as the defualt view location

  2 passing (5ms)
```

You have something strange in your implementation (maybe a singleton or a global variable somewhere) but it's not Mocha's fault.

Comment: (referring to your last comment) Using `new` does indeed break the current application and definitely isn't what I want with the app. I'll probably just re-implement the way it handles state and attach it as a property of the prototype and use `this` to access it.  It's technically a constructor internally, but I don't want the user to have to use the `new` keyword when instantiating the app. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You're welcome. You should edit you question (or even close it and post another one)